# Integrated JaCoCo results in SonarQube using Jenkins Maven Multitarget-App

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube, jacoco-maven-plugin

after fighting now with integrating JaCoCo results into my SonarQube to see code coverage for more then one working day, I will try to open another post regarding this topic, because the internet is really messed with postings.

Preconditions:

```
SonarQube: Version 6.7.2
Maven: 3.5.2
Windows Server2012 R2
```

I successfully integrated Sonar Scan and results are published. I added the configuration for JaCoCo in the pom.xml of my application and the result files are generated after the build and just using the JaCoCo Jenkins plugin they can be displayed on the Jenkins dashboard. But I did not figure out what Analysis properties the Jenkins action "Execute SonarQube Scanner" needs in order to import the results and display them.

[image]

Is "scan" the correct operation or do I need something else to trigger the import?

I saw so many variantes of giving JaCoCo and Sonar the correct parameters, that I do not have a clear picture any more. Any hints maybe looking at my parameters?

Answer (score 0):

As described [in the docs](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Jenkins#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforJenkins-AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforMaven), since you're building with Maven you should analyze with it too. There's some global setup you want to do (see the docs) but once that's done, you'll add this to your job *instead of* your current SonarQube Scanner build step:

```
$SONAR_MAVEN_GOAL -Dsonar.host.url=$SONAR_HOST_URL
```

Note that this needs to come *after* your build and test execution. The JaCoCo reports should be picked up automatically.

Comment: I am building with Maven yes, but I am using a freestyle project, because, I have to use a SAP tool for building Cloud Foundry Multi Target Application. This SAP command line triggers Maven, but it no typical Maven build. So I think my configuration is OK. I only need a hint, how I can add the JaCoCo analysis to SonarQube.

Comment: You can still add a Maven build step to a Freestyle job.

Answer (score 0):

I successfully integrated it now with these Analyses properties and it is working.

sonar.projectName=
sonar.projectKey=

sonar.login = 
sonar.password =

sonar.sources=./
sonar.java.binaries=./

sonar.jacoco.reportPaths=./trackingboard-service/target/jacoco.exec
sonar.jacoco.reportMissing.force.zero=true